# How to make a Python script an executable program

Tags: java, python, executable

To be clear, not just "run python scripts" 
But to make my python script a "executable" or "callable" program
that can be used in other programming languages or platforms. 
More like a API maybe.

The thing is I implemented several algorithms in java and 
they're supported by numpy and spipy, but others want to 
call my python program in their java program.

Then the numpy and spipy are problems. They can't be in java and 
jython...

Is there a solution that I can make this an executable program that others don't need the environment but just to run the program with several parameters accepted?

Comment: "They can't be in java and jython..." <-- why? Any incompatibilities?

Comment: try [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org) it was helpful for me :)

Comment: Because I used numpy and spipy in my program and they're actually more C/C++ based library and jython is more java based.So...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to make the python programs executable, then you can add a line to the top like this:

```
   #!/usr/bin/python
```

Replace /usr/bin/python with the filepath to python, which can be obtained by typing

```
    which python
```

into the terminal, assuming you're using a unix-based system.

You can then tell the operating system that the program is executable with

```
    chmod +x nameofprogram
```

If the java programs require something more complicated than just being able to run the python parts as executables, then you'll probably need to provide more information for anyone to be able to help you.