# Run python script with custom unix command?

Tags: python, unix

Is it possible to run my python application via a custom unix command like ls or cd. The closest I can think of is to alias python myscript.py , how do I make it work so that you only have to type myscript and the flags you want.

Comment: Put your script in the path

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/17173664/7432?

Comment: @BryanOakley yes it is thanks